# Finding an unused index in a Verilog array?

Tags: arrays, verilog

I am writing a Verilog module that needs to maintain an array. Each index can be used or unused. I am providing an interface into the module to allow a client to request a resource. I want the module to be able to lookup the next unused index & use that index to allocate that resource to a client.

I am stuck on the best way to find an unused index in Verilog. Does it make sense to stick the unused indexes in a FIFO? Or when a resource is requested, to iterate through the array to find the first unused one? Is there some other, better, Verilog pattern for handling this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you always assigning the index in order? If so, just increment a counter.  If not, what other client is grabbing values out of order?

Comment: What does 'best' mean in your case? Is it more important to find unused indexes really fast, even if it uses more logic area? Or are you tolerant to do a slow search of all indexes when you get a request, if that is a smaller design? Both of your suggested ideas seem like reasonable choices.

Comment: You'll likely get better answers if you give a bit more insight in what you are trying to accomplish. You can emulate an array using a FIFO or LIFO, which are often implemented with RAMs or register banks with read and write pointers. If you care about the order, or need to remove elements in a different order than that in which they were added, then a FIFO will not work.

Comment: Initially I assign the indexes in order. However, an index can be returned to allow it to be used again so a simple, in-order distribution won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all things the answer is "it depends"!  Some things to consider:

- What is your synthesis target and what resources are available?
- How large is the array?
- Is the array a contiguous block of memory?
- How frequently do requests occur?
- How quickly must the response be provided?
- What clock frequency are you aiming for?
- Where are you aiming in optimised implementation vs. time to market vs. device resource usage?

Without knowing the above it's impossible to provide a definite answer, however below are a few techniques you could consider.  Clearly if you can exploit some property of your particular use case there may be some optimisations (as @dwikle states in some cases a simple FIFO would be sufficient).

### Register Bitmask

Maintain a bitmask of populated entries.  This works OK for for smaller arrays where it's acceptable to use a 1-bit register for each array location.

If you need single cycle response times and must handle consecutive back-to-back requests then you can derive the next free index using a bitscan followed by a onehot to binary coder.  This is often used for arbitration or interrupt masking and you can find [code snippets](http://www.altera.com/literature/manual/cookbook.zip) and explanations in the [Altera Advanced Synthesis Cookbook](http://www.altera.co.uk/literature/manual/stx_cookbook.pdf) optimised for (previous generation) FPGAs.

This won't scale well to large arrays, but you can pipeline over multiple cycles if you don't to handle need back-to-back requests in a single cycle.

### Memory

If your target provides memory blocks and your array size is large then you can utilise a memory block to store the state.  Again there are a couple of ways to do it:

#### Store a populated flag

Similar to using a register, just use a single bit flag for each memory.  This will scale to support large arrays.  To find the next free entry you perform a search through the memory.  Typically you'd read a wide slice (say 64 bits) and then scan that vector in a single cycle using the bitscan technique above, thus your maximum search time is ARRAY_SIZE/64.  You can also build more interesting capabilities in this way, for example a [CAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory).

#### Store addresses of array locations

This has the advantage that your array doesn't necessarily need to be contiguous in memory.  The simplest way to manage this is simply have a FIFO of unused addresses and a FIFO of used addresses. This is not the most efficient mechanism but makes the logic simplistic (allocating and freeing entries is simply a case of reading an address from one FIFO and writing to the other).

Comment: I ended up using a combination of a register bitmask & a FIFO because I'm using the indexes for a few different purposes. I get the answer is "it depends", but can you give me a range for what "This won't scale well to large arrays" means? What is a large array - 10 items? 10000?

Comment: @oconnor0 Let's say you have a mid-size FPGA and 32k entries, then 32k registers is likely to be too costly relative to the size of the device.  Secondly to "bitscan" 32k registers to find the next free bit is also going to be very expensive.  Let's say that based on the target FMAX you can bitscan 256 bits in a single cycle, you'd need 17 pipeline stages (and associated registers) to bitscan the whole vector.  Ultimately though it's a trade-off between logic cost, implementation time and your design constraints.  TL;DR you probably want to look at alternatives if >1024 entries...